# How to compare a series of metrics with the same number in the metrics name

Tags: prometheus, rules, promql

Imagine we have the following 6 metrics:

```
metric1-value      metric1-value-expected
metric2-value      metric2-value-expected
metric3-value      metric3-value-expected
```

And we want to create an expression to compare these metrics based on the number of the name, That's the following:

```
metric1-value == metric1-value-expected
metric2-value == metric2-value-expected
metric3-value == metric3-value-expected
```

Something like this:

```
 {__name__=~"metric.*-value"} == {__name__=~"metric.*-value-expected"}
```

But I got the following error:

> Error executing query: many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

Is there a way to to so in the Prometheus rules file ?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the comparison to work, you need to know the name of the metrics in advance. The only way I see to achieve that would be to add a label used for identifying the corresponding expected.

The canonical way to do that is to use the [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) configuration.

If you cannot for whatever reason, you can use [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) for extracting or renaming your metrics in the query.

Extracting the id will be

```
label_replace({__name__=~"metric.*-value"},"id","$1","__name__","(metric.*)-value")
```

Then you can specify on which criteria is done the comparison

```
label_replace({__name__=~"metric.*-value"},"id",...) == on(id) label_replace({__name__=~"metric.*-expected"},"id",...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was bigger, there are also metrics with the same name but different labels:

```
metric1-value{host="host1"}      metric1-value-expected{host="host1"}
metric1-value{host="host2"}      metric1-value-expected{host="host2"}

metric2-value {host="host1"}     metric2-value-expected{host="host1"}
metric2-value {host="host2"}     metric2-value-expected{host="host2"}

metric3-value {host="host1"}     metric3-value-expected{host="host1"}
metric3-value{host="host2"}      metric3-value-expected{host="host2"}
```

Since creating an 'id' label with the first part of the metrics eg:'metric1' will cause the same error because of the multiple metric name definition.

> Error executing query: many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

What I've done is to create a external label called 'id' with the first part of the metric and the hostname eg:'metric1_host2'. To do that I've nested a label_join with a label_replace.

```
label_join(label_replace({__name__=~"metric.*-value"}, "id", "$1", "__name__", "(metric.*)-value"), "id", "_", "id", "host") != label_join(label_replace({__name__=~"metric.*-expected"}, "id", "$1", "__name__", "(metric.*)-expected"), "id", "_", "id", "host")
```

Therefore, the metrics would be like this and it will be unique:

```
metric1-value{host="host2" id="metric1_host2"}
```

Comment: Note that the ON clause can take more than one label. `== on(id,host)` should achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I can achieve the same behavior but I can't see the metric name (__name__) if I use the 'on' operator.
Therefore the result using 'on' operator would be:
`{id="metric1", host="host2"}`
And I would like to have the following result:
`metric1-value{id="metric1", host="host2"}`